# What is the correct way to add Chromecast support to a Windows/Mac app?

Tags: electron, chromium, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have a Windows/Mac Electron app. What would be the best way for me to add Chromecast support to it?

I see there is an Electron Chromecast npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-chromecast) but it is pretty old. Shouldn't there be a simpler way considering it is already using Chromium?

Thanks.